# How to create a payment intent endpoinf in Firebase while using stripe

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, stripe-payments

I am trying to create paymenyintent with stripe using firebase serverless(using functions)
My functions are    depoyed as you can se:-
[image]

It shoes error in the following Viewcontroller "error -Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

My ViewController code -

```
  import UIKit
  import Stripe

     /**
    * This example collects card payments, implementing the guide here:           https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#ios
     * To run this app, follow the steps here https://github.com/stripe-samples/accept-a-card-payment#how-to-run-locally
           */
        
      let BackendUrl = "https://console.firebase.google.com/project/totemic-point-318509/overview"

      class NewCheckoutViewController: UIViewController {
      var paymentIntentClientSecret: String?

    lazy var cardTextField: STPPaymentCardTextField = {
    let cardTextField = STPPaymentCardTextField()
    return cardTextField
    }()
    lazy var payButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
    button.setTitle("Pay", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pay), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
     }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [cardTextField, payButton])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 20
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.leftAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: stackView.rightAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: view.topAnchor, multiplier: 2),
    ])
    startCheckout()
    }

      func displayAlert(title: String, message: String, restartDemo: Bool = false) {
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        if restartDemo {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restart demo", style: .cancel) { _ in
                self.cardTextField.clear()
                self.startCheckout()
            })
        }
        else {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel))
        }
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func startCheckout() {
    // Create a PaymentIntent by calling the sample server's /create-payment-intent endpoint.
    let url = URL(string: BackendUrl + "create-payment-intent")! //  **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.**
    let json: [String: Any] = [
        "currency": "usd",
        "items": [
            "id": "photo_subscription"
        ]
    ]
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            response.statusCode == 200,
            let data = data,
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any],
            let clientSecret = json["clientSecret"] as? String,
            let publishableKey = json["publishableKey"] as? String else {
                let message = error?.localizedDescription ?? "Failed to decode response from server."
                self?.displayAlert(title: "Error loading page", message: message)
                return
        }
        print("Created PaymentIntent")
        self?.paymentIntentClientSecret = clientSecret
        // Configure the SDK with your Stripe publishable key so that it can make requests to the Stripe API
        // For added security, our sample app gets the publishable key from the server
        Stripe.setDefaultPublishableKey(publishableKey)
    })
    task.resume()
}

@objc
func pay() {
    guard let paymentIntentClientSecret = paymentIntentClientSecret else {
        return;
    }
    // Collect card details
    let cardParams = cardTextField.cardParams
    let paymentMethodParams = STPPaymentMethodParams(card: cardParams, billingDetails: nil, metadata: nil)
    let paymentIntentParams = STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: paymentIntentClientSecret)
    paymentIntentParams.paymentMethodParams = paymentMethodParams

    // Submit the payment
    let paymentHandler = STPPaymentHandler.shared()
    paymentHandler.confirmPayment(withParams: paymentIntentParams, authenticationContext: self) { (status, paymentIntent, error) in
        switch (status) {
        case .failed:
            self.displayAlert(title: "Payment failed", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            break
        case .canceled:
            self.displayAlert(title: "Payment canceled", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            break
        case .succeeded:
            self.displayAlert(title: "Payment succeeded", message: paymentIntent?.description ?? "", restartDemo: true)
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
            break
        }
    }
   }
 }

 extension NewCheckoutViewController: STPAuthenticationContext {
   func authenticationPresentingViewController() -> UIViewController {
    return self
   }
  }
```

My index.js code for functions -

```
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');
  const admin = require('firebase-admin');

   const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_51HmAsMFzRM1fSBZ2CkBBjW5a3sEpxEQLGT7OkGxa8BZMMfgzT1Jeqs7dq63AlPRLIJmzHFC0HHAmKHDazcpriuh9001IWIVmw1');
   // initialize admin SDK with defaults
   admin.initializeApp();



   // [START chargecustomer]
  // Charge the Stripe customer whenever an amount is written to the Realtime  database
    exports.createStripeCharge =       functions.firestore.document('stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{id}').onCreate(async          (snap, context) => {
   const val = snap.data();
   try {
   // Look up the Stripe customer id written in createStripeCustomer
   const snapshot = await        admin.firestore().collection(`stripe_customers`).doc(context.params.userId).get()
  const snapval = snapshot.data();
  const customer = snapval.customer_id
// Create a charge using the pushId as the idempotency key
// protecting against double charges
  const amount = val.amount;
  const idempotencyKey = context.params.id;
  const charge = {amount, currency, customer};
  if (val.source !== null) {
   charge.source = val.source;
  }
      const response = await stripe.charges.create(charge, {idempotency_key:         idempotencyKey});
     // If the result is successful, write it back to the database
   return snap.ref.set(response, { merge: true });
   } catch(error) {
  // We want to capture errors and render them in a user-friendly way, while
  // still logging an exception with StackDriver
   console.log(error);
   await snap.ref.set({error: userFacingMessage(error)}, { merge: true });
    return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
     }
  });
    // [END chargecustomer]]

  // When a user is created, register them with Stripe
  exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
 const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email: user.email});
 return     admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({customer_id:   customer.id});
    });

   Add a payment source (card) for a user by writing a stripe payment source token to Realtime database
    exports.addPaymentSource = functions.firestore.document('/stripe_customers/{userId}/tokens/{pushId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
   const source = snap.data();
  const token = source.token;
 if (source === null){
   return null;
      }

   try {
  const snapshot = await          admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(context.params.userId).get();
  const customer =  snapshot.data().customer_id;
 const response = await stripe.customers.createSource(customer, {source: token});
return     admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(context.params.userId).collection("so  urces").doc(response.fingerprint).set(response, {merge: true});
   } catch (error) {
    await snap.ref.set({'error':userFacingMessage(error)},{merge:true});
   return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
    }
   });

  // When a user deletes their account, clean up after them
  exports.cleanupUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user) => {
   const snapshot = await      admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).get();
  const customer = snapshot.data();
  await stripe.customers.del(customer.customer_id);
  return admin.firestore().collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).delete();
  });

  // To keep on top of errors, we should raise a verbose error report with Stackdriver    rather
  // than simply relying on console.error. This will calculate users affected + send   you email
   // alerts, if you've opted into receiving them.
  // [START reporterror]
    function reportError(err, context = {}) {
   // This is the name of the StackDriver log stream that will receive the log
     // entry. This name can be any valid log stream name, but must contain "err"
  // in order for the error to be picked up by StackDriver Error Reporting.
   const logName = 'errors';
    const log = logging.log(logName);

       // https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref_v2beta1/rest/v2beta1/MonitoredResource
       const metadata = {
     resource: {
      type: 'cloud_function',
      labels: {function_name: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME},
          },
         };

             // https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorEvent
      
            const errorEvent = {
    message: err.stack,
   serviceContext: {
   service: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME,
   resourceType: 'cloud_function',
      },
    context: context,
     };

     // Write the error log entry
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   log.write(log.entry(metadata, errorEvent), (error) => {
   if (error) {
    return reject(error);
   }
   return resolve();
    });
  });
  }
 // [END reporterror]  code -


 // Sanitize the error message for the user
function userFacingMessage(error) {
return error.type ? error.message : 'An error occurred, developers have been   alerted';
}
```

So, how to create paymentintent endpoing using firebase. ?
Note - I am using firestore serverless.

Edit: After rectification suggeste by Justin, the error went away, but a new error :-

[image]
Thanks.

Edit: Also added MyAPIClient:-

```
   import Stripe
   import UIKit
   
 class MyAPIClient: NSObject, STPCustomerEphemeralKeyProvider {
 let baseURL = URL(string: "https://api.stripe.com")!

    func createCustomerKey(withAPIVersion apiVersion: String,  completion: @escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock) {
        let url =   self.baseURL.appendingPathComponent("ephemeral_keys")
         var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url,  resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
        urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "api_version", value: apiVersion)]
        var request = URLRequest(url: urlComponents.url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                response.statusCode == 200,
                let data = data,
                let json = ((try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]) as [String : Any]??) else {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            completion(json, nil)
        })
        task.resume()
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

On the line where the code crashes you're force unwrapping the URL (with the `!` at the end):

```swift
let url = URL(string: BackendUrl + "create-payment-intent")!
```

That indicates the URL isn't being successfully created.  The reason is likely the value of your `BackendUrl` constant, which starts with a colon and a space:

```swift
let BackendUrl = ": https://console.firebase.google.com/project/totemic-point-318509/overview"
```

Try removing the `:`  from the beginning of that value and see if it works as expected.

Comment: build succeeds but says "rror loading page - failed to decode response from the server" - see image above please

Comment: The error indicates your server isn't returning the information expected by the iOS app.  You added a screenshot of the new error, but the code is still the same.  Can you either post a new question about this new error or update your question with your current code?

Comment: Miachael - I have updated the code. This has been bothering me for quite  a while. If you can help me with that, I will be indebted. Thank you so much, Justin.

Comment: It's likely your server is not returning JSON, so when your iOS code tries to decode the `data` as JSON it fails and presents the error you see.  What's in the `data` returned from your server?  Does the content of `data` tell you what might need to be fixed?  Can you add additional logging to determine exactly what's failing?

Comment: do you want data from the  debug console of xcode ?

Comment: @added MyAPIClient as well

Comment: No, sorry, I literally meant the `data` variable in your code from this line specifically: `let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) in`.  When that code runs what is the value of `data`? Does it contain JSON as expected or something else?  If it's something else does that give you a hint as to what the issue on the server might be?

Comment: How to find it out?

Comment: You can add code to log/display the value or [use the debugging tools in Xcode to examine the value](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UsingtheDebugger.html) when your code runs.